# UIView Doesn't Appear Immediately

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout, frame

I'm creating a `UIView` in one of my methods and going through all the steps of adding it to the view:

```
background1 = UIView(frame: CGRectInset(other.frame, -thickness, -thickness))
background1!.backgroundColor = aColor   
background1!.hidden = false
container.addSubview(background1!)
```

This is included in a method I call in `viewDidAppear()`. In general, everything works perfectly. This view, however, appears noticeably later when opening the app the first time.

I can tell, from setting breakpoints before and after the above code, that `background1` does not appear on the screen immediately after the code is executed, nor even in any place I've been able to set breakpoints.

I'm not doing anything else with the view—for some reason it takes surprisingly annoyingly long to load.

I have a very complicated (as shown by the >114 comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32240629/uiimageview-frame-doesnt-reflect-constraints)) layout setup that's part AutoLayout and part programmatic and thus would like to just resolve this issue alone, if possible, without ripping up everything else.

I know that `viewDidAppear()` is, of course, called *after the view appears*, meaning the code executed should take effect then, but from what I can tell, `background1` isn't even appearing at that point.

Additionally, as you can see in the first line of the code I posted, `background1`'s `frame` relies upon that that of `other`, another subview. This view has its frame determined by AutoLayout. [From what I understand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28510631/incorrect-frame-being-reported-using-autolayout-size-classes), it's only guaranteed that the correct `frame` will be reported after `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`is called. (Incidentally, this is even called after `viewDidLoad()`.)

I know I've already made a mistake by mixing AutoLayout and programmatic layout, but I'm hoping there's a way to salvage this. I do, in fact, remember, a time in a previous version when nearly the exact same setup was working perfectly. (Looking back through commits, though, I couldn't find it.)

**To be clear, I guess I'm asking if there's a way to force the `UIView` to appear when the code is executed.** I've tried calling the parent's `layoutSubviews()`, but that doesn't seem to work.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add the view in `viewWillAppear` rather than `viewDidAppear`?

Comment: @Paulw11 My thinking exactly. The issue with that, though, is that the frame of other view which this view's frame depends on hasn't been set by AutoLayout at that time.

Comment: Then you should use autolayout for this view too so that the layout can all be resolved at the same time.

Comment: You should create and add this view in viewWillAppear (or in viewDidLoad, it would be much elegant), and if you don't want to layout it, then set its frame in viewDidLayoutSubviews method.

Comment: What happens if you add it as a subview of `other` instead of `container` and use `other.bounds` for the calcualation?